# LabVIEW 3D sensor mapping

Tags: labview

I'm currently working with `LabVIEW 2012` and I'm about to begin a project with the 3D sensor mapping (Sensor Mapping Express VI) from LabView.

I read about it and most of the time, they're talking about `NI-DAQmx` tasks, but for my project, I'd like to use data from shared variables that I wrote.

Does anyone knows whether it is possible and/or very difficult to do that, because I also see that we can put "*free sensors to represent data you wire to the Express VI.*" So is it the answer to my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can connect your data via the free sensor input this should not give you a problem. You can even connect simulated channels if need be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.